# Two DataGrids on one row program freezing WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

A quick disclaimer: I am new to WPF and have been using its controls for a short time.

I have two DataGrids on one row:

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <DataGrid
                        Name="Map"
                        Width="Auto"
                        Height="Auto"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding MapCollectionView}">
                    </DataGrid>
                    <DataGrid
                        Name="Values"
                        Width="Auto"
                        Height="Auto" 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ValuesDataView}"/>
                </StackPanel>
 </Grid>
```

The reason for this is that the first DataGrid has static columns, whose data is in an `ObservableCollection` and is binded to a `CollectionView` but the second DataGrid has dynamically added columns - the data is stored in a `DataTable` and is binded to a `DataView`. I cannot use a `DataTable` for all the data as one of the column headers has a built in TextBox and Image and so `AutoGenerateColumns=true` won't be the move for me.

After starting the program, however, everything freezes. The constructor is executed, `OnNavigatedTo` is executed but that's about it. I removed the first DataGrid and it worked, so I'm thinking that the problem is that there are two on one row.

Has anyone encountered such thing?

ViewModel:

```
 private ObservableCollection<MapModel> mapData = new();
 private ICollectionView mapCollectionView;
 private DataTable valuesDataTable = new();
 private DataView valuesDataView;

        public ObservableCollection<MapModel> MapData
        {
            get => mapData;
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref mapData, value);
                MapCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(mapData);
                MapCollectionView.Filter = filterByName;
            }
        }

        public ICollectionView MapCollectionView
        {
            get => mapCollectionView;
            set => SetProperty(ref mapCollectionView, value);
        }

        public DataTable ValuesDataTable
        {
            get => valuesDataTable;
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref valuesDataTable, value);
                ValuesDataView = valuesDataTable.DefaultView;
            }
        }

        public DataView ValuesDataView
        {
            get => valuesDataView;
            set => SetProperty(ref valuesDataView, value);
        }
```

The values of the properties are set in the constructor. The data is taken from a REST API. Everything seems to be working as expected.

Comment: Start putting breakpoints in your code and find out where the app is crashing. Is it after all of your custom client code has executed? Is it during the adding of the dynamic columns in your second DataGrid? We need more information to help you.

Comment: @Arkane I mean that the program freezes and I cannot click anything so I go to Visual Studio and stop debugging. No exception is thrown. The problem disappears when I remove the first DataGrid. I will try adding columns in a second.

Comment: @AndrewH I put breakpoints in all the places that are called automatically -> the constructor and `OnNavigatedTo` - they are both executed. Every other method I have is called when I click a button. That's why I think that there is a problem with the displaying of the DataGrids.

Comment: @Arkane The problem still persists when removing the `StackPanel` and adding two columns. And I unfortunately cannot simplify my XAML by removing the `Grid`.

Comment: When do you assign data sources to the DataGrids? Do those assignments happen successfully? Are you able to share more code? When the app crashes, does Visual Studio give you any exception details that might point to a line number or provide a stack trace? There is nothing wrong with your XAML and you have not provided any of your C# code that could be causing the crash.

Comment: @AndrewH I updated the question. And no, no exception of any kind is thrown, the screen just freezes. I tried waiting for a couple minutes and there was no movement so I just stopped the debugger.

Comment: Nothing leaps out at me. You could try using a different control than DataGrid (e.g. ListView with a contrived data template) to see if the values are at least being data-bound correctly, then work your way backwards to the DataGrid.

Comment: Thank you very much, will do!

Comment: This sounds like you are showing a big item count in your DataGrid. The Height of the DataGrid is set to Auto. This will allow the DataGrid to stretch infinitely. If it stretches infinitely, the vertical scroll viewer is not shown. If the vertical scroll viewer is not shown the DataGrid can't make use of UI virtualization and has to load all items at once. This will make the UI freeze. If you give the DataGrid a fixed height, then the DataGrdi will show the scroll viewer and can virtualize the items: it will only load the visible items. So, give the DataGrid a fixewwd height.

Comment: This worked, thank you so much!